# Apply texture to 3D triangles using libGDX

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, textures, texture-mapping

I'm working on a 3D engine using libGDX. I'm making an external tool to create the maps and I've managed to make the walls textured. Now I'm trying to make the ceiling and floor. To create the shapes of them I use the EarClipping to create triangles which make up the shape. As you can see, it works almost good:
[image]

The shape is perfect but the material isn't applied to the ceiling - it's just a gray color. To make this I use the MeshBuilder (rects for walls and triangles make up the shape of the ceiling).
This is the code which is responsible for creating this mesh:

```
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    MeshPartBuilder meshBuilder;
    Vector3 corner00 = new Vector3(),
            corner10 = new Vector3(),
            corner11 = new Vector3(),
            corner01 = new Vector3(),
            normal = new Vector3();

    modelBuilder.begin();

    Texture wallTexture = new Texture("wall.PNG");
    wallTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
    wallTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    Material material = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(wallTexture));
    EarClippingTriangulator triangulator = new EarClippingTriangulator();


    Array<Sector> sectors = level.getSectors();
    for (Sector sector : sectors) {
        meshBuilder = modelBuilder.part("room1", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |
                        VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, material);
        Array<Wall> walls = sector.getWalls();
        for (Wall wall : walls) {
            Vertex v1 = wall.getV1();
            Vertex v2 = wall.getV2();
            meshBuilder.setUVRange(0, 0, (Vector2.dst(v1.getX(), v1.getY(), v2.getX(), v2.getY())) / wallTexture.getWidth(), 1);
            meshBuilder.rect(corner00.set(v1.getX() / PROP, v1.getY() / PROP, 0), corner10.set(v2.getX() / PROP, v2.getY() / PROP, 0),
                    corner11.set(v2.getX() / PROP, v2.getY() / PROP, 10), corner01.set(v1.getX() / PROP, v1.getY() / PROP, 10),
                    normal.set(wall.getNormal(), 0));
        }
        meshBuilder = modelBuilder.part("ceil", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |
                        VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, material);



        Array<Vertex> sectorVertices = sector.getVertices();
        float[] sectorVerticesToTri = new float[sectorVertices.size * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectorVertices.size; i++) {
            Vertex vertex = sectorVertices.get(i);
            int currentTriIndex = i * 2;
            sectorVerticesToTri[currentTriIndex] = vertex.getX();
            sectorVerticesToTri[currentTriIndex + 1] = vertex.getY();
        }
        ShortArray triangles = triangulator.computeTriangles(sectorVerticesToTri);
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.size / 3; i++) {
            int currentTriangleIndex = i * 3;
            Vertex v1 = sectorVertices.get(triangles.get(currentTriangleIndex));
            Vertex v2 = sectorVertices.get(triangles.get(currentTriangleIndex + 1));
            Vertex v3 = sectorVertices.get(triangles.get(currentTriangleIndex + 2));

            //Why these triangles don't show the texture?
            meshBuilder.triangle(
                    corner00.set(v1.getX() / PROP, v1.getY() / PROP, 10),
                    corner01.set(v2.getX() / PROP, v2.getY() / PROP, 10),
                    corner10.set(v3.getX() / PROP, v3.getY() / PROP, 10));
        }
    }
    Model worldModel = modelBuilder.end();
    instance = new ModelInstance(worldModel);
```

As you can see, This piece of code is creating the triangles:

```
meshBuilder.triangle(
                    corner00.set(v1.getX() / PROP, v1.getY() / PROP, 10),
                    corner01.set(v2.getX() / PROP, v2.getY() / PROP, 10),
                    corner10.set(v3.getX() / PROP, v3.getY() / PROP, 10));
```

PROP is just a constant to make it fit the proportions of the map tool.

I've got no idea why it doesn't work the same as the rects.
One more thing, even if the triangles did show the texture, it would have been shown one each triangle individually. Is there a way to wrap the texture on the whole shape that has been created by the triangles?

Thanks

Comment: In the triangle sample you don't seem to set the UV's anywhere.

Comment: I tried calling setUVrange after the triangles part but it doesn't seem to work. But I tried building the triangles with VertexInfo, giving to each vertex a UV vector and it actually shows the texture on them. But now the problem is that the texture is wrapped on each triangle - making the ceiling not looking as one whole shape. Any idea how can I apply the texture on the whole ceiling shape?

Comment: Might be a stupid question - do you have back-face culling on? If so could it be the order of the points?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is back-face culling? Do you mean not showing the shape on the negative side of the normal? If so, yes

Comment: But I see the triangles, so the order is correct. Their textures are just wrapped on each one of them individually. Is there a way to make the material treat the whole ceiling as one whole shape?